# Run Raspberry Pi on Hyper-V rather than terminal

Tags: raspbian

I have configured my raspberry pi device and the only way to use it through SSH terminal.
I also have installed Raspbian OS on Hyper-V (Windows 10). However, it seems that these two are to different entities running.

I would like to run my raspberry pi using Raspbian GUI as VM rather than the terminal. Is that possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Every Raspbian instance is a different entity. Why is that a problem?

Comment: I'd recommend X410.dev - no VM required by the way

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean you want to view your Raspberry Pi Raspbian Desktop from a Windows PC. This is usually done using VNC. RealVNC is pre-installed on Raspbian with Desktop.

Just enable VNC in Raspberry Pi Configuration, Interfaces. Install VNC Viewer on your Windows PC. Then using VNC Viewer connect to the local IP address of your Pi.

https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/vnc-raspberry-pi

Comment: Mentioned: "I also have installed Raspbian OS **on Hyper-V** (Windows 10)."

Comment: How can anybody run Raspbian (compiled for Arm cpu) on Windows Hyper-V?

Comment: I assume they mean ‘Raspberry Pi Desktop for PC’ https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was hoping this is possible.. Is it possible?

Comment: @CoderMike I found this solution before but I'm trying to avoid installing more apps on my laptop. So as asked by MichealHarvey, this is what I actually wanted to know.. My current Raspbian OS running on Hyper-V is different than the Raspbian run from my Raspberry device . I wish you understand haha. I don't know how else to explain.

Comment: VNC Viewer is a small app. Why don’t you want to install more apps on your laptop?

Comment: I'm trying to utilised pre-installed software. That's all :)